# Is there a way to compare "\x3C!--" with "<!--" and get 'true' in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, hex, string-comparison

In one of my projects I have to parse HTML pages and to check if each parsed "tag candidate" is in the predefined list of tag defining strings.

The problem emerges when for some reason the parser returns `"\x3C!--"` as the "tag candidate", so I get `false` when comparing it with `"<!--"` from the list.

Is there any way to get `true` comparing those strings?

UPDATE:

To clarify my question and to explain where the error occurs I add two screenshots from DevTools panel, Google Chrome, version 104.0.5083.0 (Official Build) dev (64-bit).

[image: Paused in debugger 1]

We can see that the value of `nodeParse.tagOpening` is changed almost immediately after it has been assigned. It's quite strange.

[image: Paused in debugger 2]

But it's even more strange that if I open properties of `nodeParse` object in Local Scope, the correct (initially assigned) value is shown for `tagOpening`.

So it seems the browser knows that both shown values are actually equivalent, but for some reason distinguishes them. Any comments?

Comment: Can you supply more information about the code parser being used? Given `"\x3C!--` is valid JavaScript _source code_ for a `"<!--"`, and using `eval` to compile the first into the second is a terrible idea, and the possibility that the parser is source encoding other strings as well, I suggest looking into the reason the parser is returning `"\x3C!--` more carefully.

Comment: @traktor, the parser just browses the DOM and the routine, processing each node, includes the code: `if (node.nodeName == "#comment") { nodeData.tagStarter = "<!--"; }`. Nevertheless the value of `nodeData.tagStarter` is equal to `"\x3C!--"`, I do not know why. All other parts of the node source are saved and processed correctly. For example `nodeData.tagCloser = "-->";` works as it should.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After a deeper investigation I have revealed that `"\x3C!--" == "<!--"` is always `true`, with no extra efforts (see the screenshot below).

We should keep in mind however that string `"<!--"` (and any longer one) is stored as is in a variable, but is transformed into `"\x3C!--"` when is stored in an object's property. At least in Google Chrome.

So we should assign the object's property to a variable (like `var s2 = ob.a;`), if we want to get value `"<!--"` back for sure. It was not known to me, so I have made a mistake in my code.

[image: Paused in debugger 3]

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The console logging routines of Chromium based browsers (which excludes Firefox), render `<!--` as `\x3C!--` when it occurs in a string that is a property of an object being logged. They render it normally when the string is passed to the logging routine as a primitive string argument. The "`\x3C!--`" is actually not wrong,  as it is simply "`<!--`" with '<' replaced with a valid character escape allowed in JavaScript string syntax.

Comment: As a comment the use of different code for primitive string and object logging is understandable - the first argument might be a format string, while object properties that are strings are never used as format strings. Why the code path for object property strings hex escapes `<!--` is unknown - possibly the programmer who wrote it had a good reason, possibly they only thought they had a good reason.

Answer (score 0):

Within a HTML document `<!--` is the opening delimiter for comments, even within `<script>` tags, see [HTML-like Comments](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-html-like-comments), so I would avoid including it as a string in your code.

Instead, you could just use the hex escape sequence in the tag-defining string in the first place. For example:

```js
nodeParse.tagOpening = '\x3C!--';
nodeData.tagStarter = '\x3C!--';
```

Comment: This solution works, but it is not necessary, as it seems now.